# java - MapStruct unable to map fields in base class in mapper function

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a Base dto and a dto which extends it

```
public abstract class AbstractItem {
    private String upc;
    private String quantity;

    //getter and setter for upc and quantity
}

public class OrderedItem extends AbstractItem {
    private String orderId;

    // getter and setter for orderId
}
```

Then I have a modal which I want to convert from OrderedItem. This modal extends a base modal

```
public abstract class AbstractModal {
    private String qty;

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }
}

public class ItemModal extends AbstractModal {
    private String orderNbr;
    private String upcNbr;

    // getter and setter for orderNbr and upcNbr;
}
```

this is my mapper function using Mapstruct

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "orderedItem.orderId" target = "orderNbr"),
        @Mapping(source = "orderedItem.upc" target = "upcNbr"),
        @Mapping(source = "orderedItem.quantity" target = "qty")
    })
    ItemModal convert(OrderedItem orderedItem);
}
```

During compilation I get an error `Unknown property "qty" in result type test.modal.ItemModal.`

Does Mapstruct support mapping fields of base class?
If yes, can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?
I am using java 8 and mapstruct 1.2.0

Edit: added getter and setter for `qty` in `AbstractModal`

Comment: I am not sure if this has been asked before. I couldn't find a similar question

Comment: Yes MapStruct has support for this. I tried it and this works. Can you please share the setter for the `qty` in `AbstractModal`?

Comment: One side not you don't have to use `orderedItem.upc` in your `@Mapping`. You can just use `upc`

Comment: @Filip Added getter and setter for `qty` in `AbstractModal`

Comment: Thanks, this is strange as it should work. I also created a project with the classes and it works. Can you tell me which Locale you have? Also if you could create a full reproducing project, we would be able to fix it.

Comment: I will add the project to github. Give me sometime.

Comment: Sure no problem. Write a comment or create an issue in the MapStruct [tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues) so we can have a look at it

Comment: I had the same case and I have a `@NoArgConstructor` and `@Getter` and this works.